# Mongoose-How to use a model in another model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, model

I have the following model that incorporates another model of mine. I am trying to create a object using this model in Postman but the User content is not being included. How can I do it?

```
var requestSchema = new Schema({
  paciente: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  encaminhado: { type: String }, //vem do body
  pessoaRisco: { type: String }, //vem do body
  trabalhoRisco: { type: String }, //vem do body
  estadoPedido: { type: String }, //default pendente
  resultado: { type: String }, //vazio , alterado depois
  dataExame: { type: Date },
});
```

Here it is my Postman try

```
{
    "paciente":{_id:"5eb59faf9b15a50768e2307a"}
    "pessoaRisco":"Sim",
    "trabalhoRisco":"Sim"
}
```

My expected result would be the paciente informations plus pessoaRisco and trabalhoRisco but this is the output:

```
{
    "_id": "5eb943efe1a37a1674760521",
    "pessoaRisco": "Sim",
    "trabalhoRisco": "Sim",
    "estadoPedido": "Pendente",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: You have to put  your nested object at `paciente` not `User`

Comment: I tried it too and it didn´t work. Also tried "paciente": "id" (id being the id of the pretended user)

Comment: The correct way is to put `"paciente": id" where id  should be a String of `ObjectId`. How does your id look like? Please also include in the question what you expect would be inserted into the collection

Comment: I edited it. I was thinking, maybe it isn´t working because I didn´t call the populate method in the create request one. Could it be it?

Comment: You have to pass it like this, without wrapping it in an object `"paciente": "5eb59faf9b15a50768e2307a"`

Comment: still not working 
{
    "_id": "5eb94918e1a37a1674760524",
    "pessoaRisco": "Sim",
    "trabalhoRisco": "Sim",
    "estadoPedido": "Pendente",
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: Please also include an example of what you expect in the collection, not only what you actually get .Your description might not match what I have in mind.

Comment: found the issue. It was in my create method. Thanks for the help anyway :)